# add badges to select in bootstrap (v5.2)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm working with the latest version of `Bootstrap v5.2` and `Vue 3` (just for understanding).

I've found a similar question on `Stackoverflow` but this was with an older version of Bootstrap.

I have a `select` and I want to add my `id` of my `element from my v-for` as a `badge` (Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/badge/#pill-badges) in front of the upcoming text of my `element`.

My code:

```
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <span>Select with Badge</span>
    <select class="form-select" v-model="test_select_badge">
      <option v-for="element in select_array" :key="element.id" :value="element.id">
        <span class="badge text-bg-primary me-2">{{element.id}}</span>{{element.text}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this is not working out. How can I achieve my goal? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used an `dropdown` and desigend it like a select. Than it worked out for me.